# Print in a single line without last element(python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to remove the last ','  from this code how to do it. and it should also print in a single line

```
 n=int(input())
t=int(input())
m=int(input())
s=n
for i in range(m):
    print(s,end=',')
    s=s+t
```

output is: **4,6,8,**

---

but i want it to be like: 4,6,8

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for something like this:

```
n=int(input())
t=int(input())
m=int(input())
s=n
for i in range(m-1):

    print(s,end=',')
    s=s+t

print(s)
```